# Javascript hex to decimal (BigNumber)

Tags: javascript, java, hex, decimal

I need to convert large hex to dec. I already solved it using Java. Here's my solution:

```
String input = "253D3FB468A0E24677C28A624BE0F939";
System.out.println(new BigInteger(input, 16));
```

That gives me the following output: `49499458037667732112883750526794135865`.

Very simple using Java's BigInteger class!!

I need the same result using Javascript! I tried:

```
var str = '253D3FB468A0E24677C28A624BE0F939';
console.log(parseInt(str, 16));
```

With output `4.949945803766773e+37`.

I think JavaScript's Int isn't enough for this kind. How can i achieve the same Java's output with JavaScript? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Do a little research? http://www.danvk.org/hex2dec.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a Big Int library: https://github.com/peterolson/BigInteger.js

```
var q = new bigInt("253D3FB468A0E24677C28A624BE0F939", 16); 
console.log(q.toString());
```

> 49499458037667732112883750526794135865

Comment: BigInt is now supported in browsers?